# How do I replace CR-CR-LF line endings with CR-LF?

Tags: notepad++

How do I replace CR-CR-LF line endings with CR-LF?

Comment: Is there anything that you tried, are you receiving an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In find/replace, select 'extended mode'. This allows you to use escaped characters in your query strings.  So for your purpose use this for find:

```
\r\r\n
```

And this for replace:

```
\r\n
```